# Do I even need Django?

Tags: django, reactjs, firebase, django-rest-framework

I'm currently building a website where vendors from my city can authenticate and post their products, so users can search and buy them.

I started building the website with Django; in the meantime, I was taking a beautiful ReactJS 30+ hours online course and learning how much you can do with it: not only pure frontend, e.g. Routing, GET/POST requests, Forms and validation, Authentication. My initial idea was building the website with Django Rest (backend) AND React (frontend),.

But now I have a question:
Can I build my buy&sell website with React ONLY? (maybe using some pre-made backend networks like Firebase to save/fecth data to/from a database, to save time).

In your opinion would I need some backend functionalities which would be impossible/inconvenient to implement with React, Firebase or other services? Please consider that I'm talking about a quite standard buy and sell website with authenticated vendors and buyers.

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: Try spacing your question out to make it more readable to others

Comment: you can do stuff with firebase, but you will be vendor locked. you may not be able to add new features depending firebase's offerings. using django/self managed server will complicate the system but you have the control over your data.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the type of question appropriate for this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

While you don't need to use Django, you do need to use some backend framework to connect to your database or data store. So, to answer your main question directly, you probably need some other backend system to serve your data, manage authentication tokens, etc.

Django makes it pretty simple to wire up to a REST API (Django REST Framework is my preference, too), but you might be able to get everything you need done with NodeJS, and without Django.

Even still, you're looking at some type of backend, even with NodeJS and a simple NoSQL datastore.

I think you're on the path of least resistance by using Django, DRF, and React, and with a robust database like PostGreSQL.